# How to decide which file or folder to map with host?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm new to docker and pulled plesk panel docker image from [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/plesk/plesk/). I succesfully built and ran this container using following command and created some data in it.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8880:8880 -p 8443:8443 -p 8447:8447 plesk/plesk
```

Whenever I restart container from image, I lost my data on plesk panel. Fair enough, because I'm creating a fresh container whenever I started container from scratch. I know that I need to create volumes and save data in it and mount container everytime from these volumes, it's ok. But here is my question, which file inside container will I map with host? How to decide it? Is it enough to create a volume with /data directory in every container? How to find container saves data in which of its directories?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally containers' documentation will tell you where to mount volumes. It's strange that plesk's doesn't. My initial impression from some quick googling is that plesk inside a container isn't a very mature setup. It only has a trial license and they don't really have much documentation about how to configure the container properly for production use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight. I will re-check Plesk's documentation but I guess I won't find much information about it.